# Determining function from equation

Tags: calculus, functional-equations

For arbitrary real function $f(x)$ from $[0,\infty)$ to $[0,\infty)$ which is continuous, differentiable and increasing strictly
define real function $g(x)$ to be inverse of $f(x)$
then is it possible to find all $f(x)$
such that
$
g(x)=\frac{1}{2}f'(\sqrt{x})$
holds?

sure, $f(x) = x^2$ is one possibility
but couldn't there be no more? 
Thus unique solution?
Can i solve it by techniques of DEs?

Comment: You are asking about the equation $f^{-1} = \frac{1}{2} f'(\sqrt{x})$. This seems to be a pretty difficult question. See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34052/function-satisfying-f-1-f.

Comment: Much of what's written on [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/256811/90588) can be applied directly to this problem, so you can tell a great deal about the function. For instance, $f$ must be real-analytic on $(0,+\infty)$. Other parts of the proof may require adaptation to deal with the changed functional equation. There is also part of the proof that's omitted at the end, so it might be needed to check the original source and see if the proof still holds in this case.